# Calculating derivatives (applying chain rule)

Tags: calculus

Unsure were to even start with the following question, what is this type of question called so i can look it up on khan academy.

Consider the functions $f_1(x)=\sin(x)$, $f_2(x)= \frac{1}{x}$, $f_3(x)= \ln(x)$. 
Calculate the first diffrentials of $f_i\circ f_j \circ f_k$ were $\{i,j,k\}$ are all possible permutations of the numbers $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: This is an application of the chain rule. I've updated your title.

Comment: The tag differential-equations is not appropriate here. Do you need to see all six examples of the application of the chain rule? Would one example work for you?

Comment: @Tucker Yes one example is fine, just so i know were to start with this sort of question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $6$ permutations:

$$f_i\circ f_j \circ f_k=\begin{cases}
\sin\left(\frac1{\ln(x)}\right),& i=1,j=2,k=3\\
\sin\left(\ln\left(\frac1x\right)\right),&i=1,j=3,k=2\\
\frac1{\sin(\ln(x))},&i=2,j=1,k=3\\
\frac1{\ln(\sin(x))},&i=2,j=3,k=1\\
\ln\left(\sin\left(\frac1x\right)\right),&i=3,j=1,k=2\\
\ln\left(\frac1{\sin(x)}\right),&i=3,j=2,k=1
\end{cases}.$$

Accordingly, the derivatives are:
$$\frac{\operatorname d f_i\circ f_j \circ f_k}{\operatorname d x}=\begin{cases}
\cos\left(\frac1{\ln(x)}\right)\frac1{\ln^2(x)}\frac1x,& i=1,j=2,k=3\\
\cos\left(\ln\left(\frac1x\right)\right)\frac1x,&i=1,j=3,k=2\\
\frac1{\sin^2(\ln(x))}\cos(\ln(x))\frac1x,&i=2,j=1,k=3\\
\frac1{\ln^2(\sin(x))}\frac1{sin(x)}\cos(x),&i=2,j=3,k=1\\
\frac1{\sin\left(\frac1x\right)}\cos\left(\frac1x\right)\frac1{x^2},&i=3,j=1,k=2\\
\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)},&i=3,j=2,k=1
\end{cases}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much you and @zahbaz , made it very understandable

Comment: Could you check out my other question to check if my answers are right ? only the first 3 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398127/calculating-derivatives-applying-chain-rule

Answer (score 2):

First, in case you're unfamiliar, $f \circ g$ is an alternate notation for the composite function $f(g(x))$.

$f_i\circ f_j \circ f_k$ is the same as $f_i ( f_j (f_k (x)))$. Using the circle notation is a bit cleaner. By stating that $\{i,j,k\}$ represents all permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$, we're listing listing all six arrangements of these numbers into the composites

$\quad f_1\circ f_2 \circ f_3 = \sin(\frac{1}{\ln x})$

$\quad f_1\circ f_3 \circ f_2 = \sin(\ln(\frac1x))$

and so on for the remaining four permutations.

Now you want to take the derivatives of all six, applying the chain rule. For the first of the two above, we get:

$\quad \frac{d}{dx}\sin(\frac{1}{\ln x})$ $\quad= \cos(\frac{1}{\ln x})\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(\ln x)^{-1} $ $\quad= \cos(\frac{1}{\ln x})\cdot(-1)(\ln x)^{-2}\frac{d}{dx}\ln x $ $\quad= \cos(\frac{1}{\ln x})\cdot(-1)(\ln x)^{-2}\cdot(\frac{1}{x}) $ $\quad= \frac{-\cos(\frac{1}{\ln x})}{x \ln^2 x}$