# Calculating derivatives applying chain rule,

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider the functions f1(x)=2x+1, f2(x)=sin^2(x), f3(x)=ln(x). Calculate the first diffrentials of fi∘fj∘fk were {i,j,k} are all possible permutations of the numbers {1,2,3}.

I calculated the first 3 can someone tell me if im doing them correctly

For i=1,j=2,k=3 , 2x+1(sin^2(ln(x))) derivative i got 2(sin(ln(x)) * ( 2Cos(ln(x))*1/x ))

For i=1,j=3,k=2, 2x+1(ln(sin^2(x))) i got 2(ln(sin^2(x))* ((1/sin^2(x) (cos^2(x))

For i=2,j=1,k=3 [Very unsure about this one], Sin^2(2x+1(ln(x))) i got 2Sin(2x+1(ln(x)) * (2ln(x) * 1/x

Comment: Note $f_1o f_2o f_3=f_1(f_2(f_3(x)))$. Check out the functions again!

Comment: For example, $f_1of_2of_3(x)=2sin^2(ln(x))+1$

Comment: Or, $f_2of_1of_3=sin^2(2ln(x)+1)$

Comment: write down all possibilities and then we can build the derivatives

Comment: @Peter You bloody hero ! i knew i was doing it wrong .

Comment: The tendancy in this forum is to downvote questions like this, I prefer mentioning errors I see or asking the OP's what he intends etc. It is more fruitful... Additionally, most downvoters do not consider that there are new members of this forum. Instead of downvoting, they could edit the question, if they do not agree with the layout.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: 
Chain rule can be applied as follows 
$$\frac{d}{dx}[f_1(f_2(f_3(x)))]=f'_1(f_2(f_3(x)))\cdot f'_2((f_3(x))\cdot f'_3(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f_i\circ f_j\circ f_k(x)=
\begin{cases}
\color{red}{2\sin^2(\ln(x))+1},& \text{ if } i=1,j=2,k=3\\
\color{red}{2\ln(\sin^2(x))+1},& \text{ if } i=1,j=3,k=2\\
\color{red}{\sin^2(2\ln(x)+1)},& \text{ if } i=2,j=1,k=3\\
\sin^2(\ln(2x+1)),& \text{ if } i=2,j=3,k=1\\
\ln((2\sin^2(x)+1)),& \text{ if } i=3,j=1,k=2\\
\ln(\sin^2(2x+1)),& \text{ if } i=3,j=2,k=1.
\end{cases}$$

So,

$$\frac d{dx}[f_i\circ f_j\circ f_k(x)]=
\begin{cases}
\color{green}{4\sin(\ln(x))\cos(\ln(x))\frac1x},& \text{ if } i=1,j=2,k=3\ \\
\frac{4\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)},& \text{ if } i=1,j=3,k=2\\
4\sin(2\ln(x)+1)\cos(2\ln(x)+1)\frac1x,& \text{ if } i=2,j=1,k=3\\
4\sin(\ln(2x+1))\cos(\ln(2x+1))\frac1{2x+1},& \text{ if } i=2,j=3,k=1\\
\frac{4\sin(x)\cos(x)}{2\sin^2(x)+1},& \text{ if } i=3,j=1,k=2\\
\frac{4\sin(2x+1)\cos(2x+1)}{\sin^2(2x+1)},& \text{ if } i=3,j=2,k=1.
\end{cases}$$